# "Only a few people" or "only few people"?

Tags: indefinite-article, quantifiers

Can you help me with this question pleas?

> The concert wasn't popular. Only ____ people came.

How should I complete the sentence, with *a few* or *few*?

Comment: Bard agrees with me that ***only** is a "Negative polarity item"*. It goes on to say  *Without the indefinite article "a," the NPI "few" would be ungrammatical. This is because the NPI "few" needs to be associated with **a particular example** of the quantifier "few."* In which context, ***a few***  is syntactically the same as a specific number, such as *Only 100 people voted*. I'm not sure why the article in *[a] **few** people voted* is completely optional, but it can't be prepended to ***many*** or ***some** people*.

Comment: "Only few people came" is not grammatical.  You could delete the "Only" and say "Few people came", but that's not what the quoted question is asking.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is surely over the OP's pay grade.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, *few* by itself would convey the sense of *only*. So *Only few people came* sounds a bit odd. The most natural, at least in contemporary American English, would be *Only a few people came.*

By the way, the *only* serves to make the sentence sound as though the sentence is contradicting a prior expectation, in other words that one might imagine that more people would come. Conversely, *A few people came* tends to sound as though it is countering a prior assumption that no one at all would come.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a stylistic choice. In the cited context, ***few*** must unquestionably be preceded by the indefinite article...

> 1: *The concert wasn't popular. Only **a few** people came.*

It's the word ***only*** that *forces* the need to include the article (article-less *Only few people came* is syntactically invalid). Here's a similar context (without ***only***) where the article ***is*** "optional"...

> 2: *They tried. **Few** succeeded.*
> 3: *They tried. **A few** succeeded.*

The *implications* are quite different. #2 focuses on the ***probability of failure*** (negative), where #3 emphasizes the ***possibility of success*** (positive).

---

The reason for this difference is that linguistically speaking, ***few*** is a "negative polarity item" (works in "hardly any, not enough" contexts), but ***a few*** and ***many*** are neutral or positive. See the example on [Page 1668 in this University of Chicago paper...](https://home.uchicago.edu/%7Egiannaki/pubs/HSK.chapter64.pdf)

> 4: ***Few** professors invited **any** students* <sup><sub>(**FINE**)</sub></sup>
> 4a: ****Many** professors invited **any** students* <sup><sub>(**INVALID**)</sub></sup>
> 4b: ****A few** professors invited **any** students*  <sup><sub>(**INVALID**)</sub></sup>

I added my ***A few*** after their ***Many*** because 4a and 4b both fail for the same reason (unacceptable juxtaposition of positive and negative polarity items).