# "I didn’t agree with some of the things he said." — Why is it correct to use "some" after the negation?

Tags: meaning-in-context, negation, some-vs-any

an example from the textbook "the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 359:
**(1)** *I didn’t agree with **some** of the things he said*.

As far as I know, "*some*" can't be used after negation. But in (1) it is.  Why is this so?
What does "some" mean here?

---

my variant:
**(2)** *I didn’t agree with **any** of the things he said*.

Is (2) correct?
If not, then why not?
If it is, then what does "any" mean here: its usual meaning for negative statements or maybe something else?

---

update №1:

Here is the reason I said "some" can't be used after negation:

an example from the textbook "the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 360:

> **(3)** *He hadn't eaten **some** of the meat.* — It could be used only in the special context of denying a previous utterance of "He had eaten some of the meat" or the like.

Why does (1) not need an analogous special context to be correct?
I mean: if (3) is incorrect without the special context, then why is (1) correct without it?

---

update №2:

the excerpt from the textbook where I took (1) and (3) from:

[image: the textbook "the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", pages 359-360]

Comment: The alternative that you've given means something very different than the original sentence. (1) is a very common sentence in the English language which means that they agreed with some things said but didn't agree with others, and want to focus on the disagreements. Where did your rule about not using "some" after negation come from?

Comment: If a rule applied that said "*some* can't be used after negation," this example is not that problem.

Comment: Well, what you know is mistaken. Who says *some* can't be used after a negation? The difference between some and any in your examples is day and night. Whether some or any, those utterances are completely idiomatic. And it's even in that CGEL you cite.

Comment: "As far as I know, "some" can't be used after negation" —Can you tell more about where you got this idea? The simplest answer right now is that that advice is wrong. But if you can tell more about where you found it, maybe we can talk about contexts in which it makes sense.

Comment: Oh! Maybe it means a context like "There aren't *some* dishes on the table." Waiting with interest, voting to close in the meantime.

Comment: They may be referring to this text from the [Cambridge Dictionary Online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/some): "We don’t use **weak form** some **on its own** in negative statements. We use any" (emphasis mine). If that's the case, this is neither the weak form of "some", nor is it on its own.

Comment: @YonKuma Please write an answer.

Comment: @YonKuma I added an update to my post. Tell me please it's clear now or I need to add something else.

Comment: Your new #3 uses *some* as the object of a negative verb. #1 uses *some* as the object of a preposition, some time after a negative verb. Not the same.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Does it mean we never need a special context in order that the sentence is correct if "some" after negation is the object of a preposition? If not, then in what cases can we use "some" after negation without the special context? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you need to open a separate question about how to understand that passage! Disregard the "special context" stuff. It's offering a "special" exception. It's saying you don't use "some" as a direct object... *EXCEPT* maybe in a very rare situation like responding to someone else's sentence.

Comment: Yes, no special context needed if "some" after negation is the object of a preposition. But this is not yet another rule. It's where your "rule" never applied some.

Comment: I think this is a very interesting question. As a native English speaker I know intuitively when to use some/any but I’d be interested in an answer that explains why one is grammatical over the other.

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, but it is not the original question per se. It was edited. Also, the CGEL 1.a and 2.a appear to be the same. The fact is that one can argue that both are "special circumstances". Be that as it may, I don't think one need to resort to special examples. **I don't like some cars. I don't like any cars**. Both are fine, they mean different things. I fail to see why CGEL has to drag up examples with the past perfect. I hadn't liked some vintage cars when they first showed them to me. Same thing. Some and any mean different things in a negative utterance...

Comment: With negation, *I didn’t agree with **some** of it* and *I didn’t agree with **any** of it* are both fine. *Without* the negation, *I agreed with **some** of it* is fine, but *I agreed with **any** of it* is invalid. Crucially, *I agreed with **a few** of them* and *I agreed with **few** of them* are both valid, but they mean different things. Essentially, this question is all about negative and positive parity elements in English...

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Only a few people" or "only few people"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/345106/only-a-few-people-or-only-few-people)

Comment: @AndyBonner Maybe you need to open a separate question about how to understand that passage yourself! (as I understood, such a manner of talking is a norm here). I inserted that passage into the post. It's _not_ saying you don't use "some" as a direct object. Where did you find the word "object" there???

Comment: I hope I didn't sound like I meant to cause offense; I just mean that this question is about applying the advice, but perhaps a question about the advice itself is a starting step. I'm not sure I know the best grammar terminology to describe what it's saying.

Comment: Cambridge Dictionary grammar entry  (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/some) says this is ungrammatical: "If you're looking for some book to read ..."  but in my mid-Atlantic AmE dialect it's perfectly legit.  "If you're looking for some book to read, why not give this one a try? I think you'll like it."   The context would be someone who is going through books on a shelf looking for something that interests him, but nothing appeals, and the speaker intercedes. It has a nuanced meaning that is slightly different from "If you're looking for a book to read...".

Comment: It's not negation, but I cite it to suggest that **some** might be difficult to pin down.

Answer (score 1):

"Some" is defined as "*an unspecified amount or number of*".

Amounts and numbers are different. Amounts can be non-countable quantities - for example, you can have an 'amount of water'. Numbers are always countable - for example, a number of people. So, 'some' is used in two different ways.

Your example using "*some of the meat*" is a non-countable quantity, and you are partially correct - we would often say "*he didn't eat **all** of the meat*".

But in the example in question, there were clearly definable - countable - points spoken about, some of which were agreed with, some of which were not. If you can clearly define which were which, they are countable. There is no issue with using "some" when you can define what it refers to.

In fact, your example of meat could be used with 'some' without issue if you could define what *parts* of the meat you were referring to, or if there were different *kinds* of meat that were not eaten. For example, "*I didn't eat some of the meat because it was too chewy*" means that you didn't eat the chewy parts.

Comment: Why do you think this question is about countability? Can you tie your answer back to the question to demonstrate why sentence (1) is correct despite the commonly taught rule that we use "any" with negations and "some" with affirmative statements?

Comment: @gotube The short answer to "can you use 'some' after a negation' is **yes**. All of the examples where it seems wrong, causes ambiguity etc involve non-count nouns. I see that the question has been edited, but I'm not interested in constantly editing my answers to keep up with questions; it could easily become my life's work.

Comment: The OP's question is "Why...", not a yes/no. The OP's sentence (1) is countable ("*some of the thing**s***"), so countability isn't a factor here. I think you might be on to something with the ability to define "some", along the lines of YonKuma's comment-answer, but I don't see how this answer as written would help a learner to know when it's acceptable to use "some" in a negation and when not. The edits only clarified the question. The underlying question is the same.

Answer (score 0):

When *some* means "an indefinite quantity or amount", it is usually replaced by *any* in a negative context, and often in an interrogative context:

> I've got some food here.

> Have you got any food there?

> I haven't got any food here.

But when it means "some quantity or amount less then the whole", then it does not get replaced:

> I agreed with some of the things he said (implying, not with all of them).

> I didn't agree with some of the things he said (implying, not with all of them).

You can say

> I didn't agree with any of the things he said

but that means specifically, that you disagreed with ''all'' of them, not just with some of them.